# Strange bug on post/page save

Tags: save-post, bug, automatic-updates

I have a srtange bug when I try to save/update a post. Every time I got this alert:

"Are you sure to live this page?...."

I've switched tothe original theme, disabled almost all plugins but nothing work.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience this happens when you initiate an operation (Save/Update) and then try to leave the page to do something else before the requested operation has completed.

Next time you save/update a post wait until the edit page returns to normal and displays your content. *Then* navigate away from the edit page. Chances are that you will not get that warning.

The WordPress editor is trying to tell you that it thinks you have changed your mind about doing the save/update and is trying to keep you from cancelling the operation before it has completed.

In this case it really is not a bug, its a feature.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. OK, I understand but is there a way how to disable this kind of modals?